# Какие речевые ошибки допущены учителем? Как их исправить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, коммуникативные-требования

Учитель русского языка в квалификационной работе, посвященной вопросам орфоэпии (речь идет о процессе формирования московского произношения), пишет: «Прогрессивные явления в произношении и диалектные влияния вступили в борьбу с некоторыми отжившими старыми нормами». Какие коммуникативно-речевые ошибки допущены в этой фразе? Каким образом можно их исправить?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вряд ли возможна "*борьба* явлений и влияний с нормами"
2. "Прогрессивным" принято именовать то, что направлено на *улучшение* с течением времени.
3. Излишне категоричен составной эпитет "отжившими старыми", в крайнем случае можно, констатировав неизбежность закрепления явления, назвать нормы "устаревшими".

> Современные явления в произношении, вызванные, в частности,
>   диалектными влияниями, вступили в противоречие с действующими
>   произносительными нормами.

Answer (score 0):

> Прогрессивные явления в произношении и диалектные влияния вступили в
>   борьбу с некоторыми отжившими старыми нормами.

Смысл предложения неясен. "Диалектные влияния" происходят в произношении? "Старые нормы" тоже относятся к нормам произношения? Ещё мне не нравятся "отжившие старые нормы", как будто бывают "отжившие новые". И что значит "бороться с отжившими", если их уже нет? Тогда я бы сформулировал так:

**Диалектные влияния и прогрессивные явления вступили в борьбу с некоторыми старыми нормами в произношении.**

Но теперь "произношение" оказывается далековато в предложении от "явлений и влияний", что несколько затрудняет понимание. Не уверен, что это оптимальный вариант, но он лучше первоначального, я думаю.

Answer (score 0):

Что за "прогрессивные явления": в чем они состоят и кто установил их "прогрессивность"? Из текста это неясно. Не лучше ли сказать "современные изменения"?

Называть происходящее борьбой, на мой взгляд, неверно.

"Отжившими старыми" — скорее всего, плеоназм.

Comment: Во фразе учителя неточность сочетается с излишним лаконизмом, а также со смешением реального и идеального планов. "Букет",  одним словом )